# FirebaseAuthentication.net Hangs UI on Xamarin IOS

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-authentication

I am using FirebaseAuthentication.net library for my xamarin.forms project. It works on android but on IOS it hangs UI when creating FirebaseAuthProvider. Specifically

```
FirebaseAuthProvider auth = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(Helpers.ApiKeys.firebaseApiKey));
```

this code snippet hangs the application and somehow xamarin.ios can not create FirebaseConfig object. I reinstalled library couple times but nothing changed.